# Can you have a custom attribute in yang schema?

Tags: parsing, schema, ietf-netmod-yang

I wanted to know if we could define a custom field or attribute in one of the elements leaf,list etc. For eg: Is this possible? How can we define such fields if its possible.

```
model Animal{

  leaf amphibian{
      type String;
      custom "Frog";     // Custom field which has a value "Frog"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### An "attribute" as in a "new YANG keyword"

If by "attribute" you are referring to a new YANG keyword, that has special meaning to you, then yes. YANG supports extensions. From [RFC6020](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6020#section-7.17):

> The "extension" statement allows the definition of new statements
> within the YANG language.  This new statement definition can be
> imported and used by other modules.

> The statement's argument is an identifier that is the new keyword for
> the extension and must be followed by a block of substatements that
> holds detailed extension information.  The purpose of the "extension"
> statement is to define a keyword, so that it can be imported and used
> by other modules.

> The extension can be used like a normal YANG statement, with the
> statement name followed by an argument if one is defined by the
> extension, and an optional block of substatements.  The statement's
> name is created by combining the prefix of the module in which the
> extension was defined, a colon (":"), and the extension's keyword,
> with no interleaving whitespace.

```
extension custom {
  argument object;
  description "A new YANG keyword that carries special semantics.";
}

prefix:custom "Frog"; // usage of an extension
```

The `argument` keyword in the above example is an optional substatement to an `extension` keyword and is used to indicate that the new keyword takes (mandates) an argument (a string, such as `"Frog"`).

> The "argument" statement, which is optional, takes as an argument a
> string that is the name of the argument to the keyword.  If no
> argument statement is present, the keyword expects no argument when
> it is used.
> [7.17.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6020#section-7.17.2)

Why do you need a named argument for the new keyword? YANG may be mapped to YIN, the alternative syntax expressed as XML and that is where this name becomes important.

> The argument's name is used in the YIN mapping, where it is used as
> an XML attribute or element name, depending on the argument's "yin-
> element" statement.
> [7.17.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6020#section-7.17.2)

You cannot restrict the value space of this argument per se - a YANG compiler will always recognize it as a string. But there is nothing stopping you from requiring implementations to expect certain values - you are defining the meaning of the new keyword after all.

```
extension custom {
  argument value;
  description 
    "The value of "custom" statement's argument MUST be an integer
    in the range from 1 to 5.";
}

prefix:custom 3;
```

Description statements contain normative text, so if your extension contains a `description` substatement, stating that "value of this statement's argument MUST be an integer", then an implementation will have to respect this text.

### An "attribute" as in an "XML attribute" (or a JSON equivalent)

If you meant an "attribute" in instance documents (XML, JSON,...) modeled with YANG, then the answer is no - for the most part. Pure YANG does not support modeling attributes.

However, there is a published specification for a YANG extension that allows such attributes to be defined. You can read more about that [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7952) (RFC7952). The extension is called `annotation` and is used to define YANG metadata, additional information that augments data that may already be modeled with YANG. Here's an example:

```
module using-annotation {
  namespace "org:example:using-annotation";
  prefix "ua";
  
  import ietf-yang-metadata {
    prefix "md";
  }

  md:annotation my-annotation {
    type string;
    description "This is my annotation.";
  }

  container top {
    leaf some-leaf {
      type string;
    }
  }  
}
```

This would be a valid XML instance according to the above model:

```xml
  <ua:top xmlns:ua="org:example:using-annotation">
    <ua:some-leaf ua:my-annotation="Yay!">foo</ua:some-leaf>
  </ua:top>
```

It allows an XML attribute to become valid almost anywhere.

*Reading RFC7952 may also be useful for learning how the `extension` statement actually works and how to properly define a YANG extension*.